# How do I make a Windows Mobile application with .Net?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I've written plenty of .Net code for Windows but never for Windows Mobile.  How do I make a Windows Mobile application?  My mobile device has an ARM processor so I need to cross-compile.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the SDK.  Dependent on which version of the Windows Mobile you have, but here is a link to 6:

[Windows Mobile 6 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b&displaylang=en)

In this SDK, you'll find sample code which should help you along your way.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to develop applications for the Windows Phone 7?

In that case, a good starting point is the "App Hub", http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started where you may download the latest SDK and start developing. Keep in mind that apps written for the  Windows Phone 7 are not comptible with Windows Mobile 6 and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this:

http://www.ward.nu/computer/teletekst/compile.html

I got the .cab file from here (after installing .Net Compact Framework 3.5):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\NETCFv35.ppc.armv4.cab
```

Unpacked it and renamed all the files according to _setup.xml which in in the .cab.

Then I ran this command to compile Teletekst (avaiable on the ward.nu website):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /noconfig /nostdlib /r:C:\Users\Eyal\Documents\Mio\CompileCF\NetCF\mscorlib.dll /r:C:\Users\Eyal\Documents\Mio\CompileCF\NetCF\system.dll /r:C:\Users\Eyal\Documents\Mio\CompileCF\NetCF\system.drawing.dll /r:C:\Users\Eyal\Documents\Mio\CompileCF\NetCF\system.windows.forms.dll /target:winexe /out:nosttnet.exe /win32icon:Teletekst.ico /resource:Teletekst.resources Teletekst.cs
```

The output runs on my GPS device like a charm!